# Is it possible to resize/reallocate a large chunk of memory without invalidating pointers?

Tags: c++, memory

I'm working on an Allocator system for my game engine and I'm wonder if it is possible to reallocate memory (multiple of PageSize) without invalidating the pointers that point to locations within it. Can this be accomplished using a virtual memory interface? I'm aware virtual memory paging doesn't work for DMA/pinned memory, and that its not available on consoles.

Is realloc able to do this(but not guarantee it)? I'm looking for a POSIX, Linux, or Windows api that can do this just so I have a place to start.

Also, I would appreciate any further readings relevant to creating a memory management system, thanks.

Comment: Does your game engine really require this optimization? Try to write code that minimizes the number of dynamic allocations. Consider using object-pooling for the most commonly allocated objects.

Comment: I have code that minimizes dynamic allocations, but I'm writing an allocator system for containers that need dynamic memory so they can grow. I'm also using object-pooling, but I'm using that at the container level. Having my own allocators will give me the ability to provide my own guarantees and customizability to build off of.

Comment: @DanH. This is possible. But the tradeoffs required are enormous. (Every time a pointer becomes accessible, the region it points into must be locked. And every time it becomes inaccessible, it must be unlocked.) Unless you have pretty much no other choice, find another way.

Comment: This is tricky.  It can be done, but there are usually better solutions.  You should explain why one of the simpler solutions will not work for you.  The simplest solution is to store offsets, instead of pointers, into the memory region.

Answer (score 1):

The virtuality of the address space is not all that relevant to your proposed solution.  The reason a larger block may not be possible is because there is data in the address space that you want your array to grow into.  This is the same problem on physical and virtual memory spaces.

I can see two alternative approaches.

There are two easy approaches.  First, reserve enough memory in a `std::vector`.  This does should do nothing but aquire virtual memory space on efficient systems.  Grow it as needed, and those virtual memory pages will be assigned physical pages.  This is more practical on 64 bit systems, as you have a huge memory space.

Another approach would be to create your own segmented like array.  Have a vector with unique pointers to page sized chunks, and a wrapper that hides that detail.  This adds another layer of indirection on iterator access.  Implementing fast-blit for trivially copiable types and other operations optional.

Comment: Yea I realized that about the address space. I'm already planning to use pages. I'm planning to have my pages double in size, so resizing the chunks may not be favorable since it would mess up indexing into a page array.

Comment: @danh. pages should refer to fixed size pieces of memory usually, not something you 'resize'

Comment: Each page's size would be fixed, but each new page will be doubled the previous.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a particular allocation that you're especially keen to keep in-place, it may make sense to `malloc` much more memory than initially needed.  On a modern OS, that will reserve virtual address space - which will be effectively unconstrained for any 64-bit app - and actual physical backing memory will only be sought as pages are first accessed, so an excessive initial allocation is extremely "low cost" but may prevent a need to `realloc` beyond that size.  That's much easier for you than fiddling with or replacing the allocation routines....

If you have a great many allocations, and/or a 32-bit app, you may want to pursue the ability to:

- ask `realloc` if it can operate in-place (e.g. adding an extra function argument to prevent moving to another address and returning `nullptr` when it fails); this approach reduces pointer adjustments without necessarily being more aggressive in allocating virtual address space, but you'll still need to handle having to move sometimes; and/or
- intercept `malloc` and `realloc` calls and allocate them much more virtual address space than requested to reduce (or - given application specific knowledge - eliminate) the risk of needing to move the content during a later `realloc`.

The Standard-mandated `malloc`/`free`/`realloc` interface has no hooks or options for reallocating only if in-place (and letting you know when it "fails"), so you will need to write your own routines or edit a `malloc`-et-al library.

Answer (score 0):

Without writing your own allocator, or adopting a third-party one, there is no way to grow a malloc'ed block and guarantee that it doesn't move. Realloc may move it and there's no way to force it to fail if it can't grow in place.

You might want to look into `std::deque`. It is like a `std::vector` in many respects (a growable memory array), but when elements are added, it does not ever reallocate storage for old elements or move the existing objects in memory. It does have some downsides--there's no guarantee that all the objects will be contiguous in memory, and accessing an element of the deque is *slightly* slower than accessing a vector element, as it has to first calculate which block the object is in, then calculate the location of the element within the block. Generally this should not make a noticeable difference unless it is *extremely* performance critical.

Comment: Yea, I remember reading that about realloc now. So, you're saying it is possible and I'm writing my own allocator. Can it only work if the memory is grown in place, or can I use virtual memory?

Comment: At my work, our codebase used to have a custom in-house allocator that replaced malloc/realloc/free. Its realloc had an "only in-place" flag which would either grow the block in place, or just fail. In practice it generally did not work, and was not useful in many practical scenarios. I think you are probably barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: EDIT: added a section about how `deque` may help you.

Comment: With the system I'm developing the feature isn't necessary, its more of a small optimization.

Comment: It didn't pay off for us when we did it. Later on when that code got rewritten, we just jettisoned that flag's support.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are writing it in c++:

- overload malloc()/realloc()/free() with specialized versions
- instead of using bare pointers, use a special class, say `class myptr` which

  1. When dereferenced doesn't do anything extra, just dereferences
  2. When assigned, adds the variable to a list which realloc() looks through to repoint any pointers needing adjustment.

The weakness of this is that unless are very few types of objects being pointed to, it might be tedious to get the types to simply work.  Of course, that is a suitable task for templates...

Comment: I'm no stranger to templates, I may try a system like this. I have a Value class which basically holds and pointer and has runtime type information and an allocator system behind it, so it is definitely feasible. What would be the best way to overload the malloc functions. LD_PRELOAD, or load shared lib and replace symbols? Or do you mean my own set of functions that i call separately?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that does what you asked for.  If realloc() moves the block of memory, then it finds and fixes the pointers into and within the block.  This was inspired by the BDWGC project, but they are not to blame.  The danger with this code is it will find a word in memory that looks like a pointer but is not a pointer.

```
struct dbbExprAllocFixup {
    typedef dbbExpr * dbbExprPtr;
    dbbExprAllocFixup( void *, size_t, void * );
    void CheckExpr( dbbExprPtr & );
    void CheckOne( void *, char * tag );
    void CheckRange();
    char * oldBase; // old realloc() ptr
    char * oldEnd;
    char * newBase; // new realloc() ptr
    char * newEnd;
    ptrdiff_t delta;
};


dbbExprAllocFixup::dbbExprAllocFixup( void * ob, size_t ns, void * nb )
{
    oldBase = (char *) ob;
    oldEnd = oldBase + ns;
    newBase = (char *) nb;
    newEnd = newBase + ns;
    delta = newBase - oldBase;

    dbbTrace::Output( "Expr realloc: (%p to %p) moved to %p, delta = %p\n",
        oldBase, oldEnd, newBase, delta );
}

void
dbbExprAllocFixup::CheckOne( void * p, char * tag )
{
    char * * scan = (char * *) p;
    char * value = * scan;
    if( value >= oldBase && value <= oldEnd ) {
        // This value needs fixing
        * scan = * scan + delta;
        dbbTrace::Output( "  Expr realloc: %s old value %p new value %p\n",
            tag, value, * scan );
    }
}

void
dbbExprAllocFixup::CheckExpr( dbbExprPtr & p )
{
    if( p != 0 ) {
        CheckOne( & p, "e" );
    }
}

void
dbbExprAllocFixup::CheckRange()
{
    char * * scan;
    for( scan = (char * *) newBase; scan < (char * *) newEnd; scan++ ) {
        CheckOne( scan, "r" );
    } // for
}
```

The code that calls realloc() and dbbExprAllocFixup if needed.

```
void * p = ::realloc( m_pHead, bytes );
if( p == m_pHead ) {
    // The memory did not move, do nothing
} else {
    // The memory moved
    dbbExprAllocFixup f( m_pHead, bytes, p );
    // Fix pointer in the block to locations in the block
    f.CheckRange();
    // Fix pointers outside the block that point into the block
    f.CheckExpr( pExpr->m_pRoot );
    for( int i = 0; i < pExpr->m_MLRootSize; i++ ) {
        f.CheckExpr( pExpr->m_pMLRoot[i] );
    }

    m_pHead = (dbbExprAllocChunk *) p;
} // if
```

This code is not in use so could easily have bugs.  One bug I noticed now is it uses the new size for both the old and new realloc() memory blocks.